# Selecting all searched IDs in a database

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sinatra

```
SELECT name FROM users 
WHERE id=(SELECT added_id FROM relations 
          WHERE status='1' AND adding_id=2);
```

Have this but I need to search for all the names which match this search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing wrong is to use `=` instead of `in` clause.

```
SELECT name FROM users 
WHERE id in (SELECT added_id FROM relations 
WHERE status='1' AND adding_id=2);
```

Comment: thank you man was worried right there working on a big school project

Comment: @Asylharry you need to mark the answer if I helped. :)

Comment: Ye just started the account is a newb

Comment: @Asylharry its not the way to mark the answer. delete you answer and hit the green nearby my reply.

Comment: sorry my bad really made the account 15 mins ago but thanks for the help